# what is this effect called where elements appear when i scroll down a website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I scroll down on this website different elements of the site appear and move around. what is this design called and where can i learn more about it?

[github sample](https://pages.github.com/)

Comment: I guess that is fadeIn effects using jQuery. Also you can check out parallax designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write html code like.

```
<div class='wordcomatAnimation'>
      <div> content </div>
      <div> content </div>
</div>
<div class='wordcomatAnimation'>
       <img src=''/>
</div>
```

This is my css code.

```
.wordcomatAnimation{
    position:relative;
    left:-200px;
    opacity:0;
 }
```

write js code like this.

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.wordcomatAnimation').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_objectHeight =  $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */

        if( (+bottom_of_window + bottom_of_objectHeight > +bottom_of_object) && (+bottom_of_window < +bottom_of_object + bottom_of_objectHeight ) ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1','left': '0px'},1500);

        }

    }); 

});
```

This is working for me. i hope this is help fully for you.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is the use of https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear the library for that.

OR

Like this, with calculation of scroll position, window height and other parameters.

This is just sample code.

```
var bottomScrollPosition, windowHeight, windowScrollPosition,
    _this = this;
  windowHeight = $(window).height();
  windowScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  bottomScrollPosition = windowHeight + windowScrollPosition;
  return $(".animate-in").not(".hidden").each(function(i, element) {
    if ($(element).offset().top + _this.animateInOffset < bottomScrollPosition) {
      return $(element).removeClass(_this.animateInClass);
    }
```